# Using behavior tree with custom pawn and movement component

Tags: c++, unreal-4, behavior-tree

I am trying to have a custom **APawn** along with its custom **UPawnMovementComponent** and **AIController**, to move to a location using the **MoveTo** node of a behavior tree.

I've followed the code in the engine from the **MoveTo** node in the behavior tree up to the navigation classes in order to understand how this work. What I tried so far is to have my movement component inherit from **UPawnMovementComponent** and use it to consume the input vector from its pawn (input vector that should be updated by **RequestPathMove** in **UPawnMovementComponent**).

I must have missed something as this solution isn't working and my pawn does not move at all.
Is there anything more that I should have done? Any other solution to achieve this?

EDIT:
A few things I checked:

- I have a navmesh, it displays a green area where the pawn stands
- The goal position is always in range
- There is no physical constraints on any of the component of the pawn

Comment: Have you put down a NavMesh Bounds volume?

Comment: Yes I have. I edited my post with a few more informations